# 'addOnSpace' doesn't work in some browsers when IME is processing

Tags: ng-tags-input

I'm using [ngTagsInput](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput), Angular directive.

'addOnSpace' doesn't work in Safari(using 8.0.5) when IME(Input Method Editor) is processing.

Because keycode is some strange in Safari.

'addOnSpace' is triggerd by key-down.
https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput/blob/master/src/tags-input.js#L372

And in only Safari, the keycode is not 32 but 229 when IME(Input Method Editor) is processing and we key-down space key.

Surely, [W3C Draft says](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-dom/2010JulSep/att-0182/keyCode-spec.html)

> If an Input Method Editor is processing key input and the event is
>   keydown, return 229

Is there any idea to use 'addOnSpace' even when IME is processing.

Comment: What IME are you using?

Comment: I can emulate a Japanese IME. Could you add some steps so I can reproduce your problem?

Comment: 1. set ngTagInput with 'add-on-space="true"', and run on HTML
2. set Japanese IME processing
3. input some characters, and keydown space key...but the characters are not set as a new tag.